Spinning top moving in curved spacetime
If I have a spinning top in empty space, it would take work to change the orientation of the angular momentum vector of the top. Suppose I throw a spinning top in flat space such that the direction of the angular momentum vector is the same as the direction of the velocity vector of the top. I assume to top would move in a straight line. Now, what if I did the same experiment in curved spacetime like in the vicinity of a high-mass star? The velocity vector would change its direction due to motion along curved spacetime. Would the angular momentum vector also change its direction such it will always be aligned with the instantaneous direction of the velocity vector? Why or why not?

Resource: Gravity Probe B mission. The gyro's were spinning spheres, the most spherical objects ever manufactured. The satellite was launched in 2004, data acquisition for a year, then calibration phase. An unanticipated mode of energy dissipation was recognized. New models had to be developed, to account for the effect of the dissipation. Final report released in 2011.
